# Cmake error setting compiler

Tags: linux, cmake

For some reason, CMake's C and C++ compilers are set by default to `/usr/bin/qcc`.  I've followed [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9699930/cmake-complains-the-cxx-compiler-identification-is-unknown) and tried the command

> cmake -D CMAKE_C_COMPILER=/usr/bin/gcc -D CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=/usr/bin/g++

but I get the error

> CMake Error: The source directory [current directory]/CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=/usr/bin/g++" does not exist.

Why is CMake interpreting my commands as a directory, and what is the correct way to set CMake's compilers?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You've got the right idea, however the command line you want is:

```
cmake -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=/usr/bin/gcc -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=/usr/bin/g++ <path_to_source>
```

The differences are subtle. There should be no space between the `-D` and the variable being set, which is why CMake is interpreting your variable assignment as a directory. Also CMake uses `CXX` for C++ specific variables, which keeps it consistent with Make.

Comment: Thanks, the lack of a space was not shown in the answer I followed.

Answer (score 1):

It's `CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER`, not `C++`.